# Is sizeof('ab') equal to sizeof(int) in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof, multibyte-characters

Considering I have the following program that determines the size of multibyte characters.

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout<<"size of multibyte characters : "<<sizeof('ab')<<std::endl;
}
```

My [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1gXb4XoykpWeaOrb) compiler gives an output of 4.

So I have the following questions:

- What is the size of multibyte characters literal?
- Is `sizeof('ab')` equal to `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @DimChtz: It’s actually allowed to, unfortunately

Comment: You've stumbled upon an obscure feature of the language called a [multicharacter literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) ( see bullet `(6)`). These are indeed of type `int`. They have nothing to do with multibyte character encodings (like UTF-8 or Shift-JIS)

Comment: See (6): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a so-called multicharacter literal, which unlike its single character counterpart, is not of type `char`, but of type `int` (assuming its supported). As specified in [[lex.ccon]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.ccon#2), emphasis mine:

> A character literal that does not begin with u8, u, U, or L is an
>   ordinary character literal. **An ordinary character literal that
>   contains a single c-char representable in the execution character set
>   has type char**, with value equal to the numerical value of the encoding
>   of the c-char in the execution character set. **An ordinary character
>   literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter
>   literal. A multicharacter literal**, or an ordinary character literal
>   containing a single c-char not representable in the execution
>   character set, **is conditionally-supported, has type int**, and has an
>   implementation-defined value.

So you print `sizeof(int)`, as you suspected.